# Why does torch.Tensor have a libjpeg field?

Tags: lua, torch

I see this:

```
./install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:   return torch.Tensor().libjpeg.size(filename)
```

How does Tensor get the field libjpeg? I don't see it referenced in Tensor.lua.

For more context, I am trying to debug this error:

```
 /Users/un/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:140: attempt to index field 'libjpeg' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /Users/un/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:140: in function 'loader'
    /Users/un/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:276: in function 'load'
    /Users/un/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:1067: in function 'lena'
    [string "image.lena();"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /Users/un/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:588: in function 'repl'
    .../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x0104de8640
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common practice in Torch packages is to use the tensor table as a namespace. This is a trick that is useful to do quick and dirty templated function dispatch.
For example, if you load the *nn* package, you will find the functions

```
torch.DoubleTensor.nn.L1Cost_updateOutput
torch.FloatTensor.nn.L1Cost_updateOutput
```

These are usually called according to the type of input tensor. For example:

```
input = torch.FloatTensor()
input.nn.L1Cost_updateOutput(...)
```

This is what you observe with *torch.Tensor.libjpeg**
if you use the image loading packages, then you will notice that there will be *torch.FloatTensor.libjpeg** and *torch.DoubleTensor.libjpeg**

I suspect that you might have set the default tensor type to *torch.CudaTensor*, which is when you would observe this error.
Because the image package's functions are not defined for a Cuda tensor, the functions *torch.CudaTensor.libjpeg** will not exist.

The solution for you is to set your default tensor type to FloatTensor or DoubleTensor, and create any Cuda tensors as you need them.